# Plain textfield text gets cut off after clicking on return key on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, uitextfield, iphone-keypad

One weird thing happens with my code. Everything goes well till i am typing text in the textfield but as soon as I click return key my textfield text gets cut off from bottom. For more information i have attached some screenshots of my iPhone simulator.
Here is my screen
 [image: screen at the beginning]

Then Once i start editing my textfield simulator pops up keypad
[image: textfield editing]

but as soon as i clicked on return key which is present in the keypad my text gets cut off from bottom

[image: problem arises]

Anybody can help me out?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you checked with device?

Comment: I think this is the issue of custom font file.

Comment: try with system font and check

Comment: Please post some code that you have used to create this textfield.

Comment: yes.... I have checked on device too.. Its  showing me the same error @BhadreshMulsaniya

Comment: I didn't put any code inside the textfield @NiravDoctorwala

Comment: Have you try with system font?

Comment: Yup I tried.. Issue gets solved :-)

Comment: @PriyankaKanse Okay :-)